# Using @media & Google AdSense TOS

Tags: css, adsense

I am using @media css to hide element on desktop template.

Here is how:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px), (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation : portrait) {
.ad728x90,
.ad300x600,
.ad336x280 { display:none; }
.ad300x250 { display: inline-block; }
}
```

Only ads 300x250 Will show when 320px and 480px screen.

Is this allow on google adsense TOS?

Comment: Please edit your question's title to reflect the fact that you're asking about contents of Google AdSense TOS, not about CSS.

Comment: hiding ads is incorrect and might violate the TOS. The proper way is to change the size of ads depending on screen width.

Comment: @SalmanA hi thanks for the advice. Adsense team just reply my email.

Answer (score 0):

I just receive email from Adsense Team.

Basically I get 400-500 dollar a day..

The answer is:

**NO**

Hope this will help other users.